# HtmlUnit gets table in loop but not the second time through

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm parsing a web page with HtmlUnit.  This web page has a bunch of inputs which I set programmatically and then click the submit button.  That returns the analysis results on the same page below the inputs.

The parser is working fine the first time through the loop, but not the second.  Here is the code:

```
public void getPortfolioVisualizerData(List<String>symbols) throws Exception {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.portfoliovisualizer.com/backtest-portfolio#analysisResults");
        HtmlForm form = page.getFirstByXPath("//form[@action='backtest-portfolio#analysisResults']");

        //Time Period combobox
        HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("timePeriod");
        HtmlOption option = select.getOptionByValue("4");   
        select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);

        //Start Year combobox
        select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("startYear");
        option = select.getOptionByValue("1985");  
        select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);

        //End Year combobox
        select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("endYear");
        option = select.getOptionByValue("2018");  
        select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);

        //Initial Amount text input
        HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("initialAmount");
        textField.type("10000");

        //Periodic Adjustment combobox
        select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("annualOperation");
        option = select.getOptionByValue("0");  
        select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);

        //Rebalancing combobox
        select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("rebalanceType");
        option = select.getOptionByValue("1");  
        select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);

        //Display Income combobox
        select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("showYield");
        option = select.getOptionByValue("false");  
        select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);

        //Benchmark combobox
        select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("benchmark");
        option = select.getOptionByValue("VFINX");  
        select.setSelectedAttribute(option, true);

        //Allocation 1 text input
        textField = form.getInputByName("allocation1_1");
        textField.type("100");
        HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput)page.getElementById("submitButton");
        Data data = new Data();

        for (String symbol:symbols) {
            //Asset 1 text input
            textField = form.getInputByName("symbol1");
            textField.type(symbol);

            // Now submit the form by clicking the Analyze Portfolios button and get back the second page.
            HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
            HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable) page2.getByXPath("//table[@class='table table-striped table-condensed']").get(1);   //the second table on the page
            int rowNum = 0;
            for (HtmlTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
                rowNum++;
                if (rowNum==1) continue;    //skip table header values
                int colNum = 0;
                for (HtmlTableCell cell : row.getCells()) {
                    colNum++;
                    if (rowNum==2) {
                        data.Symbol = symbol;
                        String val = cell.asText();
                        switch(colNum) {
                            case 4:  data.CAGR               = val.replace("%", ""); break;
                            case 5:  data.StdDev             = val.replace("%", ""); break;
                            case 6:  data.BestYear           = val.replace("%", ""); break;
                            case 7:  data.WorstYear          = val.replace("%", ""); break;
                            case 8:  data.MaxDrawdown        = val.replace("%", ""); break;
                            case 9:  data.SharpRatio         = val;                  break;
                            case 10: data.SortinoRatio       = val;                  break;
                            case 11: data.CorrelationToUsMkt = val;
                        }
                    }

            }
            saveStock(data);
            button = (HtmlSubmitInput)page2.getElementById("submitButton");
            form = page2.getFirstByXPath("//form[@action='backtest-portfolio#analysisResults']");
       }
    }
```

It's giving me a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0 on this line:

```
HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable) page2.getByXPath("//table[@class='table table-striped table-condensed']").get(1);   //the second table on the page
```

The table of interest is the second one on the page but the error seems to say that its not finding any tables on the second pass through the loop.  Why not?  If I enter the second symbol manually it returns the table of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add delay just before getting the table from XPath and just after hitting the click. It may happen that it tries before second page is loaded.